# Errors in code. I do not know what category it falls under

Tags: c, arrays, loops, character, sentinel

**In the new code I added. I don't think there is any problem but the program stopped after I entered the code of the item. What can I do to fix this???

```
void cart()
 {
int code, amount;
float weight, price, total_weight, total_price1;
char product[20];

switch(code)
{

case 1:
    product= "Cement";
    weight=20;
    price=18;
    break;

case 2:
    product="Concrete";
    weight=30;
    price=25;
    break;

case 3:
    product="Ceramic Tile Floor";
    weight=0.1;
    price=2.2;
    break;

case 4:
    product="Foam Insulation";
    weight=0.1;
    price=2.2;
    break;

case 5:
    product="Fibre-inforced Cement";
    weight=35;
    price=50;
    break;

case 6:
    product="Thick Glass Panel";
    weight=20;
    price=50;
    break;

case 7:
    product="Thin Glass Panel";
    weight=10.5;
    price=30;
    break;

case 8:
    product="Iron Beam";
    weight=5;
    price=10;
    break;

case 9:
    product={"Iron Rod";
    weight=1;
    price=5;
    break;

case 10:
    product="Plaster Boards";
    weight=10;
    price=15;
    break;

case 11:
    product="Quarry Tiles";
    weight=0.5;
    price=3;
    break;

case 12:
    product="Steel Beam";
    weight=5;
    price=10;
    break;

case 13:
    product="Wooden Boards";
    weight=3;
    price=5;
    break;
}

printf("\nPlease enter the amount desired:");
scanf("%d", &amount);
total_weight=weight*amount;
total_price1=price*amount;

printf("So far, the total weight and total price in the cart is %f kg & RM%0.1f", total_weight, total_price1);
}
```

The language I'm using is C.
Above is the code for my program (not the whole thing). The problem is:

```
.c|42|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[20]' from type 'char *'|
```

this error goes for all the lines with product. Did I do the array thing wrong? I want to set variable product as strings and with each case the product is different. How should I declare the variable product in the function?

Also, how can I loop it so that if the user wants, he can add another "product" and its amount to the cart. Then, add the weight and price to total weight and price. And maybe use sentinel to stop entering products?

Lastly, is there a way to simplify what I've done?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the edited code:

```
    void cart()
{
int code, amount;
float weight, price, total_weight, total_price1;
char * product;

printf("\nEnter the code of the desired product:");
scanf("%d", &code);

switch(code)
{

case 1:
    strcpy(product, "Cement");
    weight=20;
    price=18;
    break;

case 2:
    strcpy(product, "Concrete");
    weight=30;
    price=25;
    break;

case 3:
    strcpy(product, "Ceramic Tile Floor");
    weight=0.1;
    price=2.2;
    break;

case 4:
    strcpy(product, "Foam Insulation");
    weight=0.1;
    price=2.2;
    break;

case 5:
    strcpy(product, "Fibre-Inforced Cement");
    weight=35;
    price=50;
    break;

case 6:
    strcpy(product, "Thick Glass Panel");
    weight=20;
    price=50;
    break;

case 7:
    strcpy(product, "Thin Glass Panel");
    weight=10.5;
    price=30;
    break;

case 8:
    strcpy(product, "Iron Beam");
    weight=5;
    price=10;
    break;

case 9:
    strcpy(product, "Iron Rod");
    weight=1;
    price=5;
    break;

case 10:
    strcpy(product, "Plaster Board");
    weight=10;
    price=15;
    break;

case 11:
    strcpy(product, "Quarry Tiles");
    weight=0.5;
    price=3;
    break;

case 12:
    strcpy(product, "Steel Beam");
    weight=5;
    price=10;
    break;

case 13:
    strcpy(product, "Wooden Board");
    weight=3;
    price=5;
    break;
}

printf("\nPlease enter the amount desired:");
scanf("%d", &amount);
total_weight=weight*amount;
total_price1=price*amount;

printf("So far, the total weight and total price in the cart is %0.2fkg & RM%0.2f", total_weight, total_price1);
```

}

But then the following message appears:

```
.c|45|warning: 'product' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
```

and after entering any of the code numberss my program stopped working.

Also, can I know how to loop the program so the user can keep entering code of product and amount until he wants to stop?

Okay. So, I fixed it with the following code:

```
char * product="Unknown";
```

but my program still stopped working. It wont display the total  weight and price.

Comment: You might want to address this first: `code` is indeterminate in this function. It is never assigned a value, yet is evaluated in the switch check, and invokes undefined behavior as a result. Regarding your invalid assignment, how about just use `const char *product = "Unknown";` and leave the rest alone (apart from fixing the previously mentioned indeterminate code and fixing the typo Samoth is pointing out).

Comment: typo on case 9 ? `product={"Iron Rod";` remove `{`

Comment: use `strcpy(product, "string");` and case 5 too long.

Comment: @WhozCraig So, would the 'code' issue be fixed if I scan for the code first? Also, can you explain how 'const char *product = "Unknown";' works? Do I put it above with the declarations? What is "Unknown" referred to?

Comment: Its a pointer to constant char data. The "unknown" is the default value if it is never assigned in the switch below (which is never accounted for, but thats another issue, you have other variables that are in the same boat). Pointers can be on the left side of an assignment statement; arrays cannot, as the answers below are telling. Doing as i described you don't need the `product[]` *array* in the first place, but it sounds like you need to spend some time in a C-text learning about pointers first.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can't assign a constant string to a `char []`. For example

```
product= "Cement";
```

is incorrect. You should use

```
strcpy(product, "Cement");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
char product[20];
```

to

```
const char * product;
```

Comment: Is this called a pointer? I'm not supposed to put in anything I didn't learn about yet, which is pathetic but rules are rules (maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Do take care that you initialized product variable to be sufficiently large to be atleast equal to length of data + 1 (for null char) if you are to use string operations. I said so because you have declared `product[20]` but length of `"Fibre-inforced Cement";` is > 20